# aggregate similar objects summing a field

Tags: json, sum, jq

I'm trying to do that with `jq`

json input file (shorten) :

```
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 3
}   
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1.5
} 
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 4.5
} 
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 2
}
```

I would like to have for my shell script:

```
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 4.5
} 
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 6.5
}
```

How can I do to make the sum of all split value for a specific key CIS ?

I have try group_by with unsuccessfully

```
cat input.json | jq -r '.'
```

ps: before that I do a replacement

```
cat /tmp/test.json |
 jq -r ' if (.order[].orderInfo[].scannedCIS) != (0) then
 ( "replace " + (.order[].orderInfo[].CIS|tostring) + " with " +
 (.order[].orderInfo[].scannedCIS|tostring)) else null end '
```

jq --version : jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbeode

The real file look like this:

```
cat /tmp/export/export_200519110544.json | jq -rs '.[].order[].orderInfo[] |  { CIS:.CIS , split:.split }      '
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 1
}
```

the input format seems to be identical, but i get an error.

```
cat /tmp/export/export_200519110544.json | jq -rs '.[].order[].orderInfo[] |  { CIS:.CIS , split:.split } | group_by(.CIS)[] | {CIS: .[0].CIS, split: [.[].split] | add}     '
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "CIS"
```

cat /tmp/export/export_200519110544.json

```
{"order":[{"customerId":0,"medicalStructureId":0,"calendarId":0,"calendarStartDate":"20200224","userLogin":"jlemoule","endOfRefillTS":1582106743807,"refillStatus":"FULL","orderInfo":[{"boxDay":0,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":1,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":2,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":3,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":4,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":5,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":6,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":653397,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"AMLODIPINO CINFA 5 mg COMPRIMIDOS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006533970","lot":"BN4171","expDay":1,"expMonth":9,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":0,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":1,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":2,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":3,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":4,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":5,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":6,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":false,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":0,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":1,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":2,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":3,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":4,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":5,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":6,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":918839,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"KEPPRA 500 mg COMPRIMIDOS RECUBIERTOS CON PELICULA","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"918839","lot":"273460","expDay":31,"expMonth":8,"expYear":21},{"boxDay":0,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":1,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":2,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":3,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":4,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":5,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":6,"boxPeriod":1,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":0,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":1,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":2,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":3,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":4,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":5,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23},{"boxDay":6,"boxPeriod":2,"boxSubDivision":1,"split":1.0,"ifNecessary":false,"reconditionnable":true,"specialProtocol":false,"surplus":false,"CIS":603564,"scannedCIS":0,"scannedCISLabel":"BROMAZEPAM NORMON 1,5 mg CAPSULAS DURAS EFG","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"8470006035641","lot":"321","expDay":0,"expMonth":2,"expYear":23}],"orderExtBoxInfo":[{"nbBoxes":1,"CIS":698435,"scannedCIS":698435,"scannedCISLabel":"PECTOX LISINA 2,7 g granulado","fromReimportCIS":0,"CIP":"698435","lot":"19019","expDay":30,"expMonth":11,"expYear":21}]}]}
```

Comment: Not at all, thanks for the quick answer, but with the real file i have error...

Answer (score 1):

Group by CIS, for each group sum splits and put the result into a new object along with CIS value.

```
$ jq '[.[].order[].orderInfo[]] | group_by(.CIS)[] | {CIS: .[0].CIS, split: [.[].split] | add}' file
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 4.5
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 6.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it works !

```
user@machine:~$ cat /tmp/export/export_200519110544.json | jq '[.order[].orderInfo[] ]   |  group_by(.CIS)[] | {CIS: .[0].CIS, split: [.[].split] | add}'
{
  "CIS": 603564,
  "split": 14
}
{
  "CIS": 653397,
  "split": 7
}
{
  "CIS": 698435,
  "split": 7
}
{
  "CIS": 918839,
  "split": 7
}
```